# Aligning a time series to start from 0 instead of timestamps for comparisons

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I am working with a time series problem where I would like to match similarities. Since the time series which I am working has a lot of gaps I need to realign it to start from t0 - tn rather than the actual timestamps so that they are useful for my comparisons.

Example:
P1: (22-Dec-2019, 5, 0),(24-Dec-2019,3,1),(01-01-2020,2,0)
P2: (05-Jan-2020,5,0), (15-02-2020,4,1),(03-03-2020,3,0),(03-05-2020,5,1),(05-06-2020,2,0)

By aligning to start from 0:
P1: (t0, 5, 0),(t1,3,1),(t2,2,0)
P2: (t0,5,0), (t1,4,1),(t2,3,0),(t3,5,1),(t4,2,0)

After alignment to start from 0 to tn the series look a bit similar. Also, they are of unequal length and multivariate sequences.

Currently, I am performing the below approach for each set:

```
first_group_df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(first_group_df["timestamp"]) # Create to datetime
first_group_df.sort_values(by="timestamp", inplace=True) # Sort it in the order of arrival
time_index = [i for i in range(0,len(first_group_df["timestamp"]))] # Index from 0 to number of datapoints
first_group_df["time_index"] = time_index #Add it as a column
first_group_df = first_group_df.set_index("time_index") #Make it index and then drop timestamp
```

Are there better approaches to align timestamps to integer index. I also think a simple reset_index() after sorting might work. I am looking for better approaches.

Below is the reference example dataframe for one of the ids:

```
    pid  val  outcome            timestamp
0   112    5        1  22-12-2019 10:00:00
5   112    4        0  27-01-2020 11:00:00
10  112    2        1  29-01-2020 11:00:00
15  112    1        1  01-02-2020 10:00:00
20  112    5        1  01-03-2020 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['t'] = df['timestamp'].rank()
```

What you haven't specified is how to rank rows with the same time. The `rank` function accepts a `method` parameter to deal with ties. Check the documentation for details.